# pm2 change dotenv/config path

Tags: node.js, pm2, pm2-logrotate

```
pm2 start --node-args="-r dotenv/config" node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --name app -- start dotenv_config_path=.env.$NODE_ENV
```

this script works

i want this one to work as well:

```
pm2 start ecosystem.json --env env_development
```

where the dotenv_config_path is inside the env variables inside the ecosystem file.

tried adding the dotenv_config_path inside the env variables and setting the env variables using --env env_development

Comment: Could you resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **node_args** to your ecosystem file. For example:

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "development",
        "script": "./src/bin/index.js",
        "node_args": '-r dotenv/config dotenv_config_path=.env.dev',
    }]
}
```

That might work for you.